# Mean squared error in 2D, divide by pixel area or not?

Tags: mean, matlab, normalization, error, histogram

I am comparing 2D histograms using mean squared error (MSE, mean of the squared differences). These histograms have varying pixel or bin sizes. I want to compare the MSE results across these different pixel/bin sizes (i.e. is the MSE lower when the binsize is 10cm vs 1cm?).

I normalize the histograms so that they sum to 1, which I thought was a good way to approximate the Riemann sum? However, I'm not sure if they should also be divided by the area of a pixel/bin, so that they integrate to 1? The MSE calculation doesn't integrate though, it sums, which is why I'm not sure which approach is best.

EDIT: I want to compare histogram A to histogram B both made using binsize X, then I want to repeat this with binsizes Y,Z then I want to say which binsize had the least error (X,Y or Z?). I have other parameters as well as binsize but this is the basic idea. The histograms are not really comparable in terms of values, one is a probability distribution, the other is an empirical histogram made using observations. So I need a way to normalize the two histograms AND the metric I use to compare them so that I can compare across binsizes X,Y,Z.

Comment: I think the solution is to normalize the histograms so that they sum to 1, then divide by the area of a pixel, so that they integrate to 1. Then, after calculating mean squared error, multiply the result by the area of a pixel so that the result is also integrated. I think this is correct but I'm not sure why.

Comment: MSE is a poor metric for comparing histograms.  The chi-squared statistic (based on frequencies) will account for the different sampling variances, whereas MSE does not.   As for your specific question, it's unclear what you are really trying to do: are you assessing pairs of histograms *with the same bins* (but doing that for various pairs using different bins in each pair) or are you trying to *adjust for different bins* when comparing two histograms?

Comment: The former: I am assessing pairs of histograms with the same bins - but doing that for various pairs using different bins in each pair. These histograms are not frequency counts, they contain rates (Hz) so I don't think the chi-squared statistic could help me.

Comment: In more detail: what I'm trying to do is a kind of optimal binsize estimation, if histogram A is the known underlying distribution and histogram B is an empirical distribution, I want to compare them and quantify the accuracy of B wrt to A. But I want to do this for lots of different binsizes (and other parameters) and at the end be able to say parameters XYZ result in the empirical histogram that best matches the underlying distribution. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: If they contain rates, they are not histograms and it's difficult to conceive of them as representing distributions.  Please explain what is being measured and how: that is likely going to be an essential piece of information for doing this right.

Comment: There are photons hitting a detector, at the end of some time (i.e. 60 mins) we can calculate the rate (Hz or photons per second) for each position on the detector, this is our first distribution A. Now, we also have a precise prediction of where the photons should hit the detector, which resembles a 2D gaussian, this is distribution B. We can sample distribution B as finely as we want because it is a model, but we want to quantify the best binsize and smoothing for distribution A to get it to match B.

Comment: Distribution A is in Hz, distribution B is a probability distribution. So they need to be normalized and then compared in a way that would allow us to say: when distribution A is created in this way it matches distribution B more closely than the 100 other ways we tested.

Comment: In a sense, distribution A is also a probability distribution - it gives the relative likelihood of observing a photon at position X,Y. So my thought was to create distribution A using some set of parameters, sample distribution B at the same positions, normalize both so that they integrate to 1, then calculate MSE, then look for the parameters used to make A that minimize the MSE

Comment: Okay: these are really *counts* of photons and they should be expressed as such.  A good statistical approach will incorporate both the Poisson noise in the counts ("shot noise") along with other forms of noise (from the electronics, etc.), often modeled as Gaussian errors.  Your problem is one of fitting a bivariate distribution (your prediction, modulo some free parameters) to these data.  That is probably best done with a maximum likelihood fit. In simple models it doesn't matter what the bin size is and there is, in no case, any need to smooth your data to succeed.

Comment: What I am doing now is a simulation test. Under normal circumstances we only have distribution A, we don't know the underlying 'real' distribution B. We want to find a method that gives the best results in a simulation, so we can apply it later to real experimental data. I don't think MLE is correct here, we just need a method to compare two 2D distributions that is invariant to binsize (because this is one of the parameters we vary).

Comment: You will need to explain how MLE could not be correct in this setting.  So far, I cannot see anything to suggest that.

Comment: Distribution B can change, it can be Gaussian, but may not be. It might have one peak, or maybe two. I don't see how using MLE to estimate the parameters of B, in this simulation scenario, will help estimating B in the future when the distribution is completely unknown and we only have A. We just want to 'map' photon events but want to do it in a way that is closest to the real data as possible.

Comment: Your mapping amounts to transforming *something,* presumably with a finite number of parameters.  For instance, perhaps you will permit translations and isotropic changes of scale: that's three parameters defining a distribution *family.*  Apply MLE.

Comment: Mean integrated squared error (MISE) is probably the most common way to compare histograms to their probability distribution, I don't know why you don't think this approach will work.

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work.  I was suggesting a better method.  Since you seem not willing to entertain such suggestions, I will bow out of this discussion.  I continue to warmly suggest that you include all the details from these comments into an edit to your question.

Comment: There are lots of reasons why I don't think it will work which I can't explain in 500 characters at a time here. The example I gave you is a simplified version of the problem. I will look into MLE but I am also still looking for an answer to the original question.

Comment: There's plenty of space in the question itself to provide the essential details of your problem.  We don't require or even expect readers to go through the comments to understand a question and as it stands, your question is unanswerable due to the missing information.  That's why an edit is necessary.

Comment: I don't know if it really matters to the question. You could reframe the question as comparing images. What if I wanted to quantify the distance/similarity between two images that was invariant to the resolution of those images? I think my question is very specific, about the correct way to apply MISE. I do appreciate you taking the time to answer but I don't think additional experimental info is really necessary, it will only complicate things.